# Detecting border of plane in Blender Python API

Tags: python, blender, blender-2.50

I'm working on a script to generate building from plane. While having normal plane is rectangle it's quite easy - you're looking for vertices most -/+X, -/+Y, -/+Z, but what if plane is not of regular shape? Is there a nice easy solution within python api in Blender?
In fact is there any clever way to detect faces/edges/vertices on border?

Comment: Hi, did you finish this project?

Comment: yes, I did - don't remember though if this issue was used in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for border edges: these will be ones that are only attached to one face. Look at the [Mesh](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_60_release/bpy.types.Mesh.html) class, specifically the [edges](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_60_release/bpy.types.Mesh.html#bpy.types.Mesh.edges), [faces](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_60_release/bpy.types.Mesh.html#bpy.types.Mesh.faces) and [vertices](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_60_release/bpy.types.Mesh.html#bpy.types.Mesh.vertices) attributes. Unfortunately the edges don’t contain a list of what faces they belong to, so you will have to construct such a mapping, e.g.

```
EdgeFaces = {} # mapping from edge to adjacent faces
for ThisFace in TheMesh.faces :
    for ThisEdge in ThisFace.edge_keys :
        if not ThisEdge in EdgeFaces :
            EdgeFaces[ThisEdge] = []
        #end if
        EdgeFaces[ThisEdge].append(ThisFace.edge_keys)
    #end for
#end for
```

Then you just look through EdgeFaces for all keys that map to single-element lists.